# How can I remove the output layer of pre-trained model with TensorFlow java api?

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have the pre-trained model like Inception-v3.  I want to remove the output layer and use it in image cognition.  Here is the example given by tensorflow:

Just like the python framework Keras, it has a method like `model.layers.pop()`.  I tried do it with tensorflow java api.  First I tried to use dl4j, but when I imported the keras model, I got an error like this:

```
2017-06-15 21:15:43 INFO  KerasInceptionV3Net:52 - Importing Inception model from data/inception-model.json
2017-06-15 21:15:43 INFO  KerasInceptionV3Net:53 - Importing Weights model from data/inception_v3_complete
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown exception.
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.hdf5$H5File.allocate(Native Method)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.hdf5$H5File.<init>(hdf5.java:12713)
at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.Hdf5Archive.<init>(Hdf5Archive.java:61)
at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModel$ModelBuilder.weightsHdf5Filename(KerasModel.java:603)
at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModelImport.importKerasModelAndWeights(KerasModelImport.java:176)
at edu.usc.irds.dl.dl4j.examples.KerasInceptionV3Net.<init>(KerasInceptionV3Net.java:55)
at edu.usc.irds.dl.dl4j.examples.KerasInceptionV3Net.main(KerasInceptionV3Net.java:108)
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.0-patch1) thread 0:
#000: C:\autotest\HDF5110ReleaseRWDITAR\src\H5F.c line 579 in H5Fopen(): unable to open file
major: File accessibilty
minor: Unable to open file
#001: C:\autotest\HDF5110ReleaseRWDITAR\src\H5Fint.c line 1100 in H5F_open(): unable to open file: time = Thu Jun 15 21:15:44 2017,name = 'data/inception_v3_complete', tent_flags = 0
major: File accessibilty
minor: Unable to open file
#002: C:\autotest\HDF5110ReleaseRWDITAR\src\H5FD.c line 812 in H5FD_open(): open failed
major: Virtual File Layer
minor: Unable to initialize object
#003: C:\autotest\HDF5110ReleaseRWDITAR\src\H5FDsec2.c line 348 in H5FD_sec2_open(): unable to open file: name = 'data/inception_v3_complete', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0
major: File accessibilty
minor: Unable to open file
```

So I went back to tensorflow.  I'm going to modify the model in keras and convert the model to tensor.  Here is my conversion script:

```
input_fld = './'
output_node_names_of_input_network = ["pred0"]
write_graph_def_ascii_flag = True
output_node_names_of_final_network = 'output_node'   
output_graph_name = 'test2.pb'
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import os.path as osp
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
output_fld = input_fld + 'tensorflow_model/'
if not os.path.isdir(output_fld):
    os.mkdir(output_fld)
net_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
num_output = len(output_node_names_of_input_network)
pred = [None]*num_output
pred_node_names = [None]*num_output
for i in range(num_output):
    pred_node_names[i] = output_node_names_of_final_network+str(i)
    pred[i] = tf.identity(net_model.output[i], name=pred_node_names[i])
print('output nodes names are: ', pred_node_names)
from keras import backend as K
sess = K.get_session()

if write_graph_def_ascii_flag:
    f = 'only_the_graph_def.pb.ascii'
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph.as_graph_def(), output_fld, f, as_text=True)
print('saved the graph definition in ascii format at: ', osp.join(output_fld, f))
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_io

constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph.as_graph_def(), pred_node_names)
graph_io.write_graph(constant_graph, output_fld, output_graph_name, as_t  ext=False)
print('saved the constant graph (ready for inference) at: ', osp.join(output_fld, output_graph_name))
```

I got the model as .pb file, but when I put it into the tensor example, [The LabelImage example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java), I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'batch_normalization_1/keras_learning_phase' with dtype bool
 [[Node: batch_normalization_1/keras_learning_phase = Placeholder[dtype=DT_BOOL, shape=<unknown>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:285)
at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:235)
at com.dlut.cmh.sheng.LabelImage.executeInceptionGraph(LabelImage.java:98)
at com.dlut.cmh.sheng.LabelImage.main(LabelImage.java:51)
```

I don't know how to solve this.  Can anyone help me?  Or you have another way to do this?

Comment: I won't add it as an answer but will comment since you were using deeplearning4j. What version of deeplearning4j did you use? We have fixed a ton of issues with model import in the latest release. The apache tika project used it just fine. Could you give us some feedback in an issue rather than just switching? Thanks! Our transfer learning api handles this just fine if you look at our examples.

Comment: @AdamGibson I asked this in GITTER, and made a issue [iuuse](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues/3520). I followed the suggestions, downloaded the new demo he gave. But when I ran the demo, I had this exception [gist](https://gist.github.com/MoriatyC/cfc48614523ed559e6b6761ef8c559ff). People in qq group said that a lot of demo cann't be ran  successfully because of the keras2 model. But I do used the model in demo and I don't know the differences between the keras1 model and keras2 model.

Comment: Download keras 1.x and try it there and it should run fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you get from the TensorFlow Java API:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'batch_normalization_1/keras_learning_phase' with dtype bool
 [[Node: batch_normalization_1/keras_learning_phase = Placeholder[dtype=DT_BOOL, shape=<unknown>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]`

suggests that the model is constructed in a way that requires you to feed a boolean value for the tensor named `batch_normalization_1/keras_learning_phase`.

So, you'd have to include that in your call to [`run`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java#L112) by changing:

```
try (Session s = new Session(g);
     Tensor result = s.runner().feed("input",image).fetch("output").run().get(0)) {
```

to something like:

```
try (Session s = new Session(g);
     Tensor learning_phase = Tensor.create(false);
     Tensor result = s.runner().feed("input", image).feed("batch_normalization_1/keras_learning_phase", learning_phase).fetch("output").run().get(0)) {
```

The names of nodes you feed and fetch depend on the model, so it's possible that the names of the 'input' and 'output' nodes are different as well.

You might also want to consider using the [TensorFlow SavedModel format](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/SavedModelBundle)  (see also https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/310#issuecomment-297015251)

Hope that helps